# Cant start *.exe with *.bat file, yet it will start if command is run from CMD directly

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, exe

I have a script that closes a process called ncat.exe and then reopens it, or at least that's what I want it to do, but it doesn't seem to be working when I run the .bat file. Here is part of the script:

```
TASKKILL /F /IM ncat.exe* /T >nul 2>nul
ping localhost -n 3 >nul
regedit /S c:\ncatprintingPuttyDefaults.reg
cd c:\
ncat_lpt1.exe
timeout /t 10 /nobreak >nul
```

These is not starting `ncat_lpt1.exe` which has inside this script:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd c:\Program Files (x86)\Ncat
ncat.exe -l -k -p 5964 > lpt1
```

This is were it gets interesting, if I go to cmd and manually type

```
cd c:\
ncat_lpt1.exe
```

It runs right away no problem. So if done through the bat file wont work but manually it will. Mind Blown pufff...

Help? Let me know if need any other detail, I tried to explain best as I could :)

Comment: it cannot just silently not start the process. there must be errors, or any other traces of why it failed. please provide those.

Comment: and btw you need quotes around your `cd` path. maybe this is why.

Comment: NB: replace `cd c:\` with `pushd c:\`; cd would only go to the root of the C drive if the person was already in a directory under C; pushd will take you to the c:\ root regardless of where called from.

Comment: @JohnBevan ---Ok so i created a small script with this and is working: (@echo off
pushd c:\
ncat_lpt1.exe
Pause) so something is breaking it in my main script

Comment: Follow @akonsu and @JohnLBevan as well: `pushd "c:\Program Files (x86)\Ncat"` or, not changing default directory, you could write `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Ncat\ncat.exe" -l -k -p 5964`

Comment: @akonsu Not necessary - `cd` will handle unquoted paths containing spaces (it's still a good idea to quote paths with spaces though).

Comment: OMG i found it guys, just for future reference my problem was the start syntax, this corrections fixed the problem : start "" /d "c:\" ncat_lpt1.exe . I had to specify the path with /d and then the path itself in "quotes" but then the exe to run outside the "quotes". Using your suggestions and /? help a bit for experimentation, trial and error did it. Cheers to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TASKKILL /F /IM ncat.exe* /T >nul 2>nul
ping localhost -n 3 >nul
regedit /S c:\ncatprintingPuttyDefaults.reg
cd c:\
CALL ncat_lpt1.BAT
timeout /t 10 /nobreak >nul
```

Change the name of `C:\ncat_lpt1.exe` to `ncat_lpt1.bat`

(from the prompt, `ren C:\ncat_lpt1.exe ncat_lpt1.bat`  )

```
@ECHO OFF
cd c:\Program Files (x86)\Ncat
ncat.exe -l -k -p 5964 > lpt1
```

Windows uses the extension to the filename to determine how to run the file. You can't simply name a batch file with an `.exe` extension to execute it - it needs a `.bat` extension.